# How can I build a default empty object that can be differentiated from 0 in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, is-empty

I'm reading a text file that contains data about mechanical fasteners. I built an object fastener (via a class) with the following attributes :

```
type as string
number as long
master as long
slave as long
```

I want to fill a collection of fasteners:

```
Cfastener as collection
```

In the text file the type, number, master and slave can come in random order and are not always all present. In order to deal with that I defined a current fastener (sort of buffer) and a default "empty" fastener:

```
currentfastener as fastener
initfastener as fastener
with initfastener
    .type = "-1"
    .number = -1
    .master = -1
    .slave = -1
end with
```

I read my text file and when I detect a keyword that refers to one of these attribute I test for the value in `current fastener`:

```
Do until .atendofstream
    line = .readline
    Select case line
        Case masterkeyword
            if currentfastener.master <> -1 then 'We already have a master. This means that we need to save the currentfastener and start a new one.
                Cfasteners.add currentfastener
                currentfastener = initfastener
            else 'master is "empty": we fill the currentfastener. 
                currentfastener.master= "value read from the text stream"
            end if
    End Select
Loop
```

Until now I’m using `-1` for numbers and `"-1"` for string as default empty argument. Until now it was fine because the arguments could not get this value. But now, I want to add a spatial position for the master and slave, and it can be `-1`. So I wanted to go back to my first idea that was do define all `initfixation` arguments as `empty`.

But if I’m not mistaken it is not possible to differentiate the `0` value from the `empty` value in vba, and this will cause trouble.

Do you know a default value, that is not 0, that can be differentiated from 0 and that is not -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Empty` is used with the `Variant` type. Setting a `String` or `Long` to `Empty` and then testing its emptiness with `IsEmpty()` won't work.

You *can* use variants to store your data, however, and then you can safely use the `Empty` value to signify an empty/missing value.

You're right that VB will cast `Empty` to `0` for numeric comparisons. For example:

```
Dim v As Variant
Debug.Print (v = 0)        ' => True
```

But you can use the `VarType()` function to test if a variant has the `Empty` value:

```
Dim v As Variant
Debug.Print VarType(v) = vbEmpty    ' => True (empty/uninitialized)
v = 0
Debug.Print VarType(v) = vbEmpty    ' => False
v = Empty
Debug.Print VarType(v) = vbEmpty    ' => True (empty)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Usually I'm not a big fan of variant, I prefer to have all my variables declared with the right type. In this case though, I see no other solution so I will use it. Still, I don't know if I will use variant for all the arguments: easier to understand and to duplicate (I have many more things to read in fact) or just use it for the arguments that can have the value -1 : probably faster and with less type related errors. I'll see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Declare all of these a variant.

```
 type as string
 number as long
 master as long
 slave as long
```

Their default value after being declared will be vbEmpty.

You can test for this

```
Dim av As Variant

If IsEmpty(av) Then Debug.Print "if isempty(av ) "

' I Wouldn't use this (it works but is overkill)
' If VarType(av) = vbEmpty Then Debug.Print "If VarType(av)= vbEmpty "
```

You can assign Empty explicitly eg

```
av = Empty
```

VB will cast Empty to 0 for numeric comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Usually I'm not a big fan of variant, I prefer to have all my variables declared with the right type. In this case though, I see no other solution so I will use it. Still, I don't know if I will use variant for all the arguments: easier to understand and to duplicate (I have many more things to read in fact) or just use it for the arguments that can have the value -1 : probably faster and with less type related errors. I'll see.

Comment: I agree. I feel very uncomfortable using variants.  When you use VBA variables to store data that has come from a database table, if the fields in the table allow NULL values then all the variables need to accomodate storing NULL.  So they all need to be variant as this is the only data type that stores NULL (ie empty).  What a bugger.

Comment: BTW Null is not the same as empty - see my answer below (in case you are interested)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ExperimentsWithVariants()

Dim avar As Variant

' is not set

' When a variant has not been assigned

Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print "NOT SET:"
Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print "aVar = Empty ", (avar = Empty)      ' True
Debug.Print "aVar", avar                         '             '' ie blank
Debug.Print "IsNull(aVar)", (IsNull(avar))       ' False
Debug.Print "IsEmpty(aVar)", (IsEmpty(avar))     ' True
Debug.Print "aVar = """"", (avar = "")           ' True
Debug.Print "aVar = 0", (avar = 0)               ' True

If avar = Empty Then
    Debug.Print " "
    Debug.Print "avar = Empty so the above would be the saem if you set avar = Empty explicitly"
    Debug.Print " """
Else
    avar = Empty
    Debug.Print " "
    Debug.Print "-----------------------"
    Debug.Print " SET TO Empty"
    Debug.Print "-----------------------"
    Debug.Print "aVar = Empty ", (avar = Empty)      ' True
    Debug.Print "aVar", avar                         '            '' ie blank
    Debug.Print "IsNull(aVar)", (IsNull(avar))       ' False
    Debug.Print "IsEmpty(aVar)", (IsEmpty(avar))     ' True
    Debug.Print "aVar = """"", (avar = "")           ' True
    Debug.Print "aVar = 0", (avar = 0)               ' True
End If

avar = Null
Debug.Print " "
Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print " SET TO NULL"
Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print "aVar = Empty ", (avar = Empty)      ' Null
Debug.Print "aVar", avar                         ' Null
Debug.Print "IsNull(aVar)", (IsNull(avar))       ' True
Debug.Print "IsEmpty(aVar)", (IsEmpty(avar))     ' False
Debug.Print "aVar = """"", (avar = "")           ' Null
Debug.Print "aVar = 0", (avar = 0)               ' Null


avar = ""
Debug.Print " "
Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print " SET TO """""
Debug.Print "-----------------------"
Debug.Print "aVar = Empty ", (avar = Empty)      ' True
Debug.Print "aVar", avar                         '            '' ie blank
Debug.Print "IsNull(aVar)", (IsNull(avar))       ' False
Debug.Print "IsEmpty(aVar)", (IsEmpty(avar))     ' False
Debug.Print "aVar = """"", (avar = "")           ' True
Debug.Print "aVar = 0", (avar = 0)               ' False
' Note
' Is empty returns false, whereas ="" returns NULL




End Sub
```